# How to mount Virtualbox shared volumes in Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running Docker toolbox on Windows, using Virtualbox to run things.

I can run a container and share a folder on my windows machine which I've called DockerShare and it's been added as a "Shared Folder" to the virtualbox machine.

This command works fine:

```
docker run -it --name api -p 8802:80 -v /DockerShare/api:/app microsoft/aspnetcore-build:latest
```

I wanted to do this using a docker-compose script:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    image: microsoft/aspnetcore-build:latest  
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - "8802:80"
    volumes: 
      - /DockerShare/api:/app
```

But this returns an error

> ERROR: for api  Cannot create container for service api: create
>   \DockerShare\api: "\DockerShare\api" includes invalid characters for
>   a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed
>
> ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I'm running this from the Dockershare folder in the ssh.

Should this work? How should I format the volume string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it works as it is. However one needs to make sure the environment is set properly. 
Docker-compose will try to mess around with the address otherwise.

Simply creating a file called ".env" in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml file with the following line:

```
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=0
```

meant it worked fine.

Comment: For people not bothering to read and for whom its not working, just replace the "0" by "1".